# Looping through multiple checkboxlists to build an email

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I am creating a form with multiple CheckBoxLists (8 total) like this:

```
Configurar el Sistema (1-3 horas)
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="Configurar">
<asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1" class="submenu" runat="server"  Text="Personal"/>
<asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1a" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Seguridad del Sistema"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1b" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Configuración del     agencia (sitios, salones)"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1c" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Configuración de los módulos (elegibilidad, requisitos de salud)"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1d" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Configuración del sistema (preferencias, Campos de específicos a su agencia)"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1e" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Utilidades  del Database (archivo, función de adiestramiento)"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1f" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Los datos de registro historia"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1g" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Configuración del PIR"/>
 <asp:ListItem ID="ECheckBox1h" class="submenu"  runat="server" Text="Configurar Data en vivo"/>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

On SubBtn.Click, the selected items would go into an email. I'm using this to loop through the first CheckBoxList:

```
    Dim ConfigurarChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In Configurar.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            ConfigurarChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurarChkVal) Then
        ConfigurarChkVal = ConfigurarChkVal.Substring(1)
    End If

    Dim EmailBody As String
    EmailBody = EmailBody + "<p style=" + "font-family:Verdana;" + ">" + ConfigurarChkVal + "</p>"
```

It returns:

> Configurar el Sistema
>
> ersonal
>
> Seguridad del Sistema
>
> Configuración del agencia (sitios, salones)
>
> Configuración de los módulos (elegibilidad, requisitos de salud)
>
> Configuración del sistema (preferencias, Campos de específicos a su agencia)
>
> Utilidades del Database (archivo, función de adiestramiento)
>
> Los datos de registro historia
>
> Configuración del PIR
>
> Configurar Data en vivo

So it cuts off the first letter of the first selected value. How do I solve this? It's not really the main problem though -- If I try to use the same code for the remaining CheckBoxLists, it only returns the last CheckBoxList instead of all 8 in the email.

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but any advice would be appreciated.

---

The code for all 8:

```
    Dim EntradaChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In FamilyServices.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            EntradaChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(EntradaChkVal) Then
        EntradaChkVal = EntradaChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If


    Dim HealthChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In Health.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            HealthChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(HealthChkVal) Then
        HealthChkVal = HealthChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If

    Dim FamilyChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In FamServices.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            FamilyChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(FamilyChkVal) Then
        FamilyChkVal = FamilyChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If


    Dim AdminChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In Admin.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            AdminChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(AdminChkVal) Then
        AdminChkVal = AdminChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If

    Dim StatusChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In StatusCenter.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            StatusChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(StatusChkVal) Then
        StatusChkVal = StatusChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If


    Dim ReportsChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In Informes.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            ReportsChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(ReportsChkVal) Then
        ReportsChkVal = ReportsChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If
    Dim OptionalChkVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In Opciones.Items

        If item.Selected Then
            OptionalChkVal += item.Value + "<br />"
        End If
    Next
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(OptionalChkVal) Then
        OptionalChkVal = OptionalChkVal.Substring(0)
    End If
```

I realized the issue was this:
            EmailBody = EmailBody + "**Configurar el Sistema** " + "

"
            EmailBody = EmailBody + "" + ConfigurarChkVal + ""

```
        EmailBody = "<p style=" + "font-family:Verdana;" + "><p style=" + "font-family:Verdana;" + "><strong>Informacion de entrada para la familia y matriculados </strong> " + "</p><p></p>"
        EmailBody = EmailBody + "<p style=" + "font-family:Verdana;" + ">" + EntradaChkVal + "</p>"
```

I left out the EmailBody + on each of the concurrent statements, which started the EmailBody over again.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you mean by using the same code for the remainining lists (can you add the code for another list and your code-behind for handling it?)

Comment: @Joe, after I was going through the code to show, I realized I left out EmailBody + and then the email built correctly. I guess the first character being cut off really was the major issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are indexed starting at zero so  `ConfigurarChkVal.Substring(1)` should be `ConfigurarChkVal.Substring(0)`

Comment: Terrific. That solved the issue with the first character disappearing. Thank you!